# Truncate rows of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, truncate

Code to create sample dataframe:

```
Sample = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': [[.332, .326], [.058, .138]]},
     {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': [[.234, .246], [.234, .395], [.013, .592]]},
     {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': [[.084, .23], [.745, .923], [.925, .843]]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(Sample)
```

Sample Dataframe visualized:

```
 df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326], [.058, .138]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], [.234, .395], [.013, .592]]
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.084, .23], [.745, .923], [.925, .843]]
```

**I looking for a formula to truncate the 'Mar' column so that any row with shape larger than (2,x) is truncated, resulting in the following df**

```
 df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326], [.058, .138]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], [.234, .395] 
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]
```

Comment: For reference, this code can truncate a single row, but not every row
-
del df['Mar'][1][2:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operations on a cell level can easily be done using `.apply` function, combined with `lambda` operator:

```
df["Mar"] = df["Mar"].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
```

Answer (score 5):

`str` accessor is designed for string operations but for iterables like lists, you can use it for slicing too:

```
df['Mar'] = df['Mar'].str[:2]

df
Out: 
   Feb  Jan                               Mar    account
0  200  150  [[0.332, 0.326], [0.058, 0.138]]  Jones LLC
1  210  200  [[0.234, 0.246], [0.234, 0.395]]   Alpha Co
2   90   50   [[0.084, 0.23], [0.745, 0.923]]   Blue Inc
```

Comment: This also works! I think its a little computationally expensive? Or something, because when I run it on a large dataframe it kills my kernel. Still awesome for the specified question though

Comment: @AshleyO When I test it the performance is about the same. I just concatenated your df 100k times though, it may not represent the actual case. One advantage of this is that it handles missing values too. Other than that, apply is of course more flexible. You can use all the operations that you want to use on lists.

Comment: I must have tried something wrong :( You were first also. I owe you a checkmark

Comment: I think Marjan was the first to answer. In any case, there is nothing wrong with selecting the one that solved your problem, don't worry about it. :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help :)

Comment: This is my preference

Comment: IMO this answer is more idiomatic compared to the accepted one

Comment: Although in this particular case @ayhan's answer indeed is more readable and appealing, I think that being comfortable with `apply-lambda` approach can save your ass with a bit more complex or custom manipulations, where no built-in method exists.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas doesn't play particularly nicely with lists in series, so it might work better to pull this out before working on it:

```
df['Mar'] = [row[:2] for row in df['Mar'].tolist()]
```

`%timeit` results for this and the excellent answers by ayhan and Marjan:

3 rows:

```
%timeit df['Mar'].str[:2]
10000 loops, best of 3: 154 µs per loop

%timeit df['Mar'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
10000 loops, best of 3: 133 µs per loop

%timeit [row[:2] for row in df['Mar'].tolist()]
The slowest run took 5.51 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 12 µs per loop

>>>5.51*12
66.12
```

3,000,000 rows:

```
%timeit df['Mar'].str[:2]
1 loop, best of 3: 1.23 s per loop

%timeit df['Mar'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])
1 loop, best of 3: 1.25 s per loop

%timeit [row[:2] for row in df['Mar'].tolist()]
1 loop, best of 3: 940 ms per loop
```

If you're willing to split the lists pairs into two columns, you can get a method that scales a bit better to larger dataframes than the above with

```
>>>pd.DataFrame(df['Mar'].tolist()).iloc[:, :2]]
                0               1
0  [0.332, 0.326]  [0.058, 0.138]
1  [0.234, 0.246]  [0.234, 0.395]
2   [0.084, 0.23]  [0.745, 0.923]
```

On 3,000,000 rows:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(df['Mar'].tolist()).iloc[:, :2]
1 loop, best of 3: 276 ms per loop
```