# Adding Zero Arrays to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

**I'm looking for code to add [0,0] arrays to the 'Mar' column if the shape is smaller than (3,)**

Sample Dataframe visualized:

```
 df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326], [.058, .138]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], [.234, .395], [.013, .592]]
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]]
```

**Again: I'm looking for code to add [0,0] arrays to the 'Mar' column so that any row with shape smaller than (3,x) is modified, resulting in the following df**

```
 df:
  account        Jan      Feb          Mar
Jones LLC  |     150   |   200    | [.332, .326], [.058, .138], [0, 0]
Alpha Co   |     200   |   210    | [[.234, .246], [.234, .395],[.013, .592] 
Blue Inc   |     50    |   90     | [[.084, .23], [.745, .923], [0, 0]
```

Code to create sample dataframe:

```
Sample = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': [[.332, .326], [.058, .138]]},
     {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': [[.234, .246], [.234, .395], [.013, .592]]},
     {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': [[.084, .23], [.745, .923]]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(Sample)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add extra values,

```
df['Mar'] = df['Mar']+[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

then trim it down, using a method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548582/truncate-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe).

Comment: Thank you so much. Great idea. Not exactly pythonic but it works